# Evaluation in proof of master theorem

Tags: algorithms

I'm having trouble understanding how the second step evaluates to the last part. I can see 9 and the denominator of 10 over 9 cancels each other out. So there should still be 10 in the last part. And where does subtraction of 1 goes?

$T(n)=O(n^2)⋅\frac{\frac{10}{9}^{1+log_3^n}−1}{\frac{10}{9}−1}=O(n^2)⋅9⋅(\frac{10}{9}⋅(\frac{10}{9})^{log_3n}−1)=O(n^2\frac{10^{log_3n}}{3^{2⋅log_3n}})$

So what I think is -

$T(n)=O(n^2)⋅\frac{\frac{10}{9}^{1+log_3^n}−1}{\frac{10}{9}−1}=O(n^2)⋅(\frac{10}{9}⋅(\frac{10}{9})^{log_3n}−1)=O(n^2.10\frac{10^{log_3n}-9}{3^{2⋅log_3n}})$